# Why is 100% height not 100% of the browser height?

Tags: html, css

EDIT:**Removed the files from the server**

http://www.jdxsolutions.com/newsite/index.html
http://www.jdxsolutions.com/newsite/default.css

This is a layout I've been using to try out some stuff. What's got me stumped is that when the browser is resized so a vertical scroll-bar appears, the background doesn't reach the full height of the browser window... in fact they are shorter than the content panel, despite being set as height:100%.

This happens in IE8, FF3 and Chrome so it's clearly a pretty standard-compliant screw-up (passes validation for XHTML 1.0 strict and CSS2.1+)! Can anyone point out the obvious mistake?

EDIT: I looked at it in Firebug as suggested. What I find is the page div sticks out past the bottom of the parent pageOutline div. How can that work?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The short answer: It's complicated. To really understand all the factors that affect CSS 100% heights (and widths) you'll need to know about terms such as: the view port,  initial containing block, flow, overflow, inline formatting contexts, block formatting contexts, the W3C box model, the IE box model and Quirks Mode.

If you're really interested on getting on top of it there is no better place to start than the spec: [The Visual Formatting Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html)

### But here's an overview.

Heights on inline elements are calculated differently than block elements -- so from here on this only refers to block elements or elements which have been given new block formatting contexts.

To start with when you give an element 100% height, it will take it's height from it's containing block eg. it's parent and it's parent takes it's height from it's parent and so-forth back to the initial containing block.

The initial containing block is different in HTML (body) and XML/XHTML (html) and it's default height isn't 100% of the viewport so normally you would cover your butt and define it this way:

```
html, body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
```

We had to zero the margin and padding because in CSS the Height property refers to the height of the Content Box and if there was any margin or padding (or border) we'd get a scrollbar. The height would be 100% + padding + border + margin... [W3C Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)

The exception to this is if IE is in [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode)... [IE box model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug)

...so unless you maintain this "100% height" through all descendant elements then you are redefining the meaning of "100% height" to each new descendant.  This can also be affected by the creation of a new Block Formatting Context. You create new bock formatting contexts when you Float or Absolutely Position an element (as well as [some other things](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting))

### About the height of Table cells...

People often ask "Why won't my Div with 100% height work in a table cell?".

This has to do with how a Table cell's height is calculated. When a cell is rendered the height of it's content box isn't stretched to match the height of the parent Row. The renderer instead adds extra padding as required so that the overall height matches the height of the Row. So in this example...

```
<tr>
   <td>
      line one<br>
      line two<br>
      line three
   </td>
   <td>
      <div style="height:100%">
         Hello world!
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

...the height of the Div is 100% -- 100% of the cell's Content Box. The cell's content box was given extra padding so that it matched the overall height of the row. The Div's height is 100% of it's parents content box (not the overall height).

See [Table height algorithms](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#height-layout).

*As this question seems to be asked almost daily I've check the Wiki check box -- I'm a newbie but presumable this will make it easier for others to make corrections and additions as needed*.

Answer (score 1):

Set the height of your page in the body to an exact number and then 100% for everything else.

Plus, there is no height here:

```
#page
{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

For the height to work correctly, every parent element must have a height set (which it appears you have done) - but the page element does not specify a height.

Try using Firebug in Firefox to see what it is reading and if it is inheriting.

Comment: I don't follow. I can't set a height on my page <div>, because it contains other elements which could have a variable size. The whole point is it should scale to fit the contents, surely?

Comment: If the page is set to 100% height (view area) then that is relative to the browser window. A scroll bar changes the view area height and thus your page is still set to the same value it was previous. If you set the top level height to a value like 2000px and 100% for the child elements you will get what you are needing.

Comment: Basically the browser view area changes but the browser does not refresh your page to display the new value when using 100%. Instead use a value and it will remain the same.

Comment: "a value"? On which div specifically? I've uploaded a newer version, all divs have name/id so could you edit your post to specify exactly what you'd change?

Comment: html, body { height: 1200px; }
Just make the 100% to a px value in the top most value.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. For one thing I get a scroll-bar at all times. Also, while it kind of works otherwise in FF, not in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You use position:absolute; this takes the element out of ‘normal flow’ which means that the element no longer has an effect on the boxes generated by its containing element.

So any of the childs under #pageOutline will fall outside the ‘normal flow’ -- the only reason why your page ‘works’ when you view it without scroll bar is that in this scenario the height:100% corresponds to the height of the viewport which is at that point larger than -or equal to height of the #pageOutline element.

You might have better luck with display:inline-block; and float properties.

Comment: On which divs? All my attempts to do this break totally.

Answer (score 0):

```
body { height: 100%; }
```

this is the height of the browser viewport, not the size of your html page.

if you need two background you could create two divs containing the other elements with different background properties

Comment: I added height as a test to body, html tags to test. Removing them makes no difference.

Comment: height and width on outer elements still matches the browser viewport, the "body" tag was just an example