# Height 100% Error

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve a repeating vertical background that has a 100% height. Sad to say, whenever I tried to expand the height of my page by just adding plain text, the background that has a 100% height and with a background repeat gets chopped off. I would just like to keep the background repeating. Here's the screenshot.

http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v682/markeeh/heighterror.png

Hope some knows the solution. Thanks. :)

Source code can be seen here:

http://interfaceflor.asia/productlaunch/colourplay/try.php

Comment: can you edit post your and add css?

Comment: Are you sure your image doesn't contain that whitespace?

Comment: Here's a related question that explains why it's *not* working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239045/why-is-100-height-not-100-of-the-browser-height

Comment: lol josh. thats vista in classic mode. hahaha! :)

Answer (score 1):

remove your `height: 100%` attribute and just use `background-repeat: repeat-y`

**EDIT**

based on your update and looking at your code, you won't be able to do what you're trying to do with two disparate divs. you need to set one background on your `<body>` tag and then create a `<div>` wrapper for your whole page and set the other background to that. put the rest of your code inside your wrapper.

or create two wrapper divs, but i would set one on the body.

Comment: I think there are two backgrounds, applied to two `div` elements, there, and he wants them to be flush with the left and right sides of the viewport.  He's probably setting `height:100%` on the divs to get them to be as tall as the page.  Just a guess.

Comment: that's possible. but either way, setting the height to 100% sets it to 100% of the height of the viewport, not of the wholly rendered page

Comment: yup, what i need is the height of the whole rendered page. so far, no luck. even tried using JS, but im just getting the viewport height.

Comment: hi jason, i edited my post with the link of the source code. thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting a background into two different elements, and setting their heights to 100%, I think you could benefit from using CSS3's multiple backgrounds.

http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: as much as i would like to use css3, i need to cater for ie6 users as well. thanks for the help though. :)

Comment: The more you cater to them, the more they'll keep using ie6... ;)