# SWF refuses to scale vertically

Tags: html, flash

I'm trying to embed a SWF in a simple HTML page such that it scales to fill the browser window. I didn't create this SWF and lack the tools to edit it, but it's doing something quite odd - it scales to fill the browser horizontally but refuses to scale vertically:

[image]

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<title>Conforming HTML 4.01 Transitional Template</title>
</head>
<body>

<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="100%" height="100%">
<param name="movie" value="Snow001.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<PARAM NAME="SCALE" VALUE="default">
<embed src="Snow001.swf" quality="high" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="100%" SCALE="default" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>

</body>
</html>
```

I've been staring at this HTML for far too long now and I can't see anything wrong with it. Is this a problem with my code or with the SWF itself? If it's a problem with the SWF what do I need to have the Flash guys do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this CSS:

```
html, body, object { height: 100%; }
```

Comment: That appears to have done it! Specifically, setting the `body` height to 100% seems to be the thing that makes this work. We should probably consider this to be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239045/why-is-100-height-not-100-of-the-browser-height) and I'll just chalk it up to a brain fart that I forgot that body height doesn't always default to 100%.