# How can i keep the margin/ between to HTML elements constant in the same Div when the size of one changes

Tags: html, css, margin

I have this issue with margins in HTML elements. This is an example of the code.

```
<body>
  <div>
    <h1>...some text...</h1>

    <p>..some quote</p>

    <button>New Quote</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

On click of the `button`, the quote in `<p>` changes. So the height of p element increases or decreases depending on the length of the quote. 
This then moves the position of the button up or down the page. I don't want to button to move up or down. I can do this by putting the button in a separate div but is it possible to set a margin between `<p>` and `<button>` such that the position do not change?

Thanks

Comment: No, the margin is relative to other elements, in this context is relative to the height of p or in general to the previous element. You can use an absolute or fixed position for your button, but is difficult to say without known your layout and your goal.

Comment: It is a random quote site. The layout is with bootstrap and the code above is exactly how the div being discussed is. fixed position didn't work because, on mobile or smaller views, the text will overflow the position of the button element. I will try the relative positioning

Comment: If the text runs over the button on a narrow screen, then you should lower the button more. None of the solutions in Andrei's answer will solve the problem of simply allotting not enough room for the quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do this and it has absolutely nothing to do with Twitter Bootstrap. It's general HTML + CSS, therefore applying to Twitter Bootstrap, too.

Considering the following generic HTML structure:

```
<container>
    <quote>
        some quote
    </quote>
    <button>
        some button
    </button>
</container>
```

... you have the following ***alternative*** options:

1. `min-height` on `<quote>`, big enough to cover all current possible `height`s of your `<quote>`s

```css
container quote {
  min-height: 50vh;
}
```

2. `min-height` and `padding-bottom` on `<container>` and place `<button>` absolute, to bottom:

```css
container {
  min-height: 50vh;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  position: relative;
}
container button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
}
```

3. `min-height` on `<container>` with `flexbox` column layout with `justify-contents:space-between;`:

```css
container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 50vh;
  justify-contents: space-between;
}
```

An alternative to `justify-contents: space-between`, if you prefer your `<quote>`s to always grow in the available space (i.e. it has a `background-color`) is `flex-grow:1` on `<quote>`:

```
container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 50vh;
}
container quote {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Feel free to replace `50vh` in the above examples with your desired height (in `px`, `em`, `rem`, `cm`, `in`...). Unless it's inside a container with physical `height` or `min-height` (expressed in in the above units — a.k.a. *hard* units) using `%` will not make your element get the desired height, because it will be `%` of `<body>` height, which is not the viewport height - unless specified otherwise, it's the sum of all resulting heights of its normal flow contents.

To understand why `<body>`s 100% height is not the viewport's 100% height, one would need understand [VFM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Visual_formatting_model) properly (or [VBM](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-speech-1/#box-model-def) as I see it called officially now).
A good overview of [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html) can be found in this SO [Community curated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4130281/1891677).

Comment: Great thanks. The first option was enough. Though 80vh was sufficient.